# Store multiple values in 1 field Django (Postgres)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My plan is to have a model that is able to store multiple values in 1 row. Basically what I want is that when a user submits my form, than it will save the weight the height and the current date. And for example the user does the same thing a month later than he will have 2 values. (They will be displayed on a graph).
Thanks in advance!

## Models File

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='user_profile')
weight = ArrayField(
    models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True),
    null=True,
    
)
height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
date = ArrayField(
    models.DateField(auto_now_add=True),
    null=True,
    
)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

## Views file

```
def home(request):
form = WeightForm()
if request.is_ajax():
    profile = get_object_or_404(request.user.user_profile)
    form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return JsonResponse({
            'msg': 'Success'
        })
       
    
return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

## Forms

```
class WeightForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['weight','height']
```

## Update:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='user_profile')
weight = models.FloatField()
height = models.FloatField()
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: Please don't. Make a model where you store `weight` and `height`, and make a `ForeignKey` to the user, such that the same user can thus generate *multiple* records. `ArrayField`s, are not a good idea in relational databases.

Comment: Hello, I updated my models file, but now on my admin page, there are 0 profiles (because I removed "save-user-profile" method). Could you give me a correct example about this please?